# Is this possible that i can add context menu at TreeItem rather then TreeView in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

i am new to JavaFX. I made the custom TreeCell using this reference:-

http://fxexperience.com/2012/05/listview-custom-cell-factories-and-context-menus/

It perfectly worked for me. But my case is that i do not want to apply this context menu to child nodes. At start there is only single TreeItems and at later stage these TreeItems have child so the try to check isLeaf() method does not make a sense because at starting the TreeItems are at leaf level but later they become parent.

So any idea how can i achieve this.

Thanks a lot.

**Update:**
At initial stage of my project there is tree having three childs(mail service providers) as follows:-

```
---Gmail  
---Yahoo  
---Rediff
```

After i connect these providers then they have this structure:-

```
Gmail
   |____Inbox
   |____Sent
Yahoo
   |___Inbox
   |___Sent
   |___Drafts
Rediff
   |___Inbox
```

Now i want context menu only on Gmail,Yahoo and rediff and not on the inbox or sent item.

I know the setContextmenu() method but this is available for the TreeView and not for the TreeItem.

Comment: It's unclear where you want a context menu, where in a tree or list?  It's possible to add one on any control with .setContextMenu

Comment: How many levels does the tree have and on which levels do you want context menus ?

Comment: How about some sample code to show how you are building your tree.

Comment: Hi brian, thanks for replying, i want ContextMenu on tree. I am agree with you that we can apply only on one control like the TreeView but i want to add the same context menu for the Treeitems. .setContextMenu() will add context menu for all the tree items but i do not want to add context menu for all the tree items.

Comment: Thanks Jurgen for replying, Initially my tree have zero level only and at later stage it becomes one level tree as i shown in my asked question now. see i updated the question details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make your tree items a descendant class of TreeItem like `public class ProviderTreeItem extends TreeItem` and a different descendant with the boxes like BoxTreeItem.

That way you won't test for isLeaf but you can test the TreeItem type.

```
if (thisTreeItem.getClass() == ProviderTreeItem.class)
   thisTreeItem.setContextmenu(providerContextMenu)
else thisTreeItem.setContextmenu(boxContextMenu)
```

It would be easier to just get the context menu from the subclassed TreeItem.

You don't really need to subclass TreeItem, you could just use the name or something like the userData object to distinguish between node types.  If you subclass then you can add different methods and properties to the different node types.

For example the boxes will need a data structure to hold emails but the the providers don't need this.  The providers need a web address and password etc., but the boxes don't need that.

Here's the updated example.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TVexample extends Application {
public abstract class AbstractTreeItem extends TreeItem{
    public abstract ContextMenu getMenu();
}

public class ProviderTreeItem extends AbstractTreeItem{
    // make class vars here like psswd
    public ProviderTreeItem(String name) {
        this.setValue(name);
    }

    @Override
    public ContextMenu getMenu(){
        MenuItem addInbox = new MenuItem("add inbox");
        addInbox.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            public void handle(Event t) {
                BoxTreeItem newBox = new BoxTreeItem("inbox");
                    getChildren().add(newBox);
            }
        });
        return new ContextMenu(addInbox);
    }
}

public class BoxTreeItem extends AbstractTreeItem{
    //private List<String> emails = new LinkedList<>();
    public BoxTreeItem(String name) {
        this.setValue(name);
    }

    @Override
    public ContextMenu getMenu() {
        return new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("test"));
    }
}

private final class TreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString());
            setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
            setContextMenu(((AbstractTreeItem) getTreeItem()).getMenu());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane sceneRoot = new StackPane();
    TreeItem treeRoot = new TreeItem();
    treeRoot.setExpanded(true);
    ProviderTreeItem gm = new ProviderTreeItem("gmail");
    ProviderTreeItem yh = new ProviderTreeItem("yahoo");
    treeRoot.getChildren().addAll(gm,yh);
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(treeRoot);
    treeView.setShowRoot(false);
    treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
        @Override
        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
            return new TreeCellImpl();
        }
    });
    sceneRoot.getChildren().add(treeView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(sceneRoot, 300, 500);


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brian, i am trying your method and will tell you as it get worked for me.

Comment: @Vikas Sharma, I read the other answer and I forgot that the menu is on TreeCell.  I wrote my answer on a computer without java installed.  Sorry I'll fix it up, but it's more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. Work Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative could be to check to see if the parent of the TreeItem is the root item. The following snippet would go in your TreeCell:

```
public void updateItem( Object item, boolean empty )
{
    super( item, empty );
    TreeItem  thisTreeItem = getTreeItem();

    if ( thisTreeItem.getParent() == rootItem )
       thisTreeItem.setContextmenu( providerContextMenu )
    else thisTreeItem.setContextmenu( boxContextMenu )
    .
    .
}
```

Although this is simpler I think Brian's answer is more elegant, and also has other advantages as he described.

Comment: i agree with you but at the initial stage Gmail,Yahoo, Rediff are not parent, in that case the context menu will not be added to these TreeItems and i want the Context menu on these TreeItems. One more thing is that i canot see a method setContextMenu for any TreeItem. it is available only for the TreeView. I am also trying the Mr. Brain method , thanks for the help Jurgen. Please keep helping me until i sort out this problem.

Comment: actually i am understanding what you said and i think you are right..give me time to give it a try.

Comment: Just to be clear the snippet of code is for your TreeCell and not for TreeItem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my favorite utility method for defining cellFactory in `TreeView`. Firstly, it sets `TreeCell` conversion to `String`, secondly, it applies `ContextMenu`.

```
public static <T> void setCellFactory(TreeView<T> treeView,
                                      ToStringConverter<T> converter,
                                      ContextMenu contextMenu) {

treeView.setCellFactory(tc -> {

  TreeCell<T> cell = new TreeCell<T>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);
      if (empty) {
        setText(null);
      } else {
        setText(converter.toString(item));
      }
    }

  };

  cell.emptyProperty()
      .addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
        if (isNowEmpty) {
          cell.setContextMenu(null);
        } else {
          cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        }
      });

  return cell;

  });

}
```

`ToStringCoverter` is interface

```
public interface ToStringConverter<T> {
  String toString(T t);
}
```